# Understanding react js code

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js. I am trying to understand a piece of code.

In parent component:

```
< childComp onSearchChange={this.someParentMethod} />
```

In child component:

```
interface childCompProps {
onSearchChange: (
    string1: string,
    string2: string) => void;
}

export class childComp extends React.Component<childCompProps,{}> {
constructor(props: childCompProps) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
   return (
           <Button
                type="primary"
                onClick={() => this.props.onSearchChange(
                    this.state.string1,
                    this.state.string2)}>
                Search
            </Button>
     )
  }
```

}

How does the call flow works in this case? When is the parent method called? What is exactly passed during onClick?

Answer (score 0):

In your child component, you've declared that it'll have this state containing two strings but they weren't initialised.

The parent component handler for the `onSearchChange` prop will receive whatever you pass to it from the child component.

The `onClick` handler in a button receives a value that represents the event.
In your code, since your'e calling a handler that's received through props, the only context the handler will have is exactly what you pass as arguments, nothing more, nothing less.

Answering your final question, the handler on the parent component will be called exactly when the event fires (as expected, when the button is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example in c# (an oops logic) which is similar to above scenario.

**What am I going to do**

> - An interface with a void method

```
interface IChildComponent
{
    public void OnSearchChange(string string1, string string2);
}
```

> - Create a class `A` and inherit this interface to the class
> - Invoke the method of interface in main method instance

```
//my component
class A : IChildComponent
{
    public void OnSearchChange(string string1, string string2)
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A instaceA = new A();  //consider this as component

        //this is basically a button click in your component which will be a method of IChildComponent Interface
        instaceA.OnSearchChange("hello", "world");
    }
}
```

**How its similar to your component?**

You are creating an interface

```
interface childCompProps {
onSearchChange: (
    string1: string,
    string2: string) => void;
}
```

You are creating a component (a class basically)

```
 class childComp
```

And inheriting interface with it with extends keyword

```
export class childComp extends React.Component<childCompProps,{}>
```

So in `childComp` class you are getting interface methods as properties that are accessible directly because it uses inheritance structure, Similarly in my example I created an instance of that class and used interface method's abstract declaration which is `instaceA.OnSearchChange("hello", "world");`

so when you do

```
onClick={() => this.props.onSearchChange(
```

is basically a method from interface `childCompProps` as properties for that class due to inheritance.

Hope this makes sense.